# Open cart not use $this->db->query in model file

Tags: php, sql, opencart2.x

Working in open cart model view controller structure I know `$db` is library file and it store in page load and set key value in registry file. So my question is in model file some place open cart use.path of file is `catalog\model\order\order.php`.

```
 $order_query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `'.DB_PREFIX."order`
```

But in same model file, in some places the open cart does not use this variable.

```
 $sql = '
    SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX."order_sellerhistory
```

Comment: check the next line after this.

Comment: Devpro can you explain more about this question i am not understand what you talking about.but thanks for replay.

Comment: u r talking about open cart not using this `$this->db->query` for second query.

Comment: i told u, check the code after this line, check where this variable is using `$sql`

Comment: Do u mean somewhere they put entire query in `query()` function and somewhere they use like `query($sql or any var)` ?